# Can (and how do) you install Ubuntu in F2FS filesystem?

Tags: installation, filesystem, ssd

[F2FS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS) is a file-system optimised for use in NAND memories (SSDs, USB flash drives, memory cards, etc...).

You can read a more complete information [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/518988/).

Is it possible to install Ubuntu in it?. Does the installer support it?. Any caveats?

Comment: It looks like it requires kernel 3.8... maybe I should wait a month to ask it, the answer could be much easier with 13.04

Comment: yeah was reading up on it before making an answer :D 3.8 should arrrive in March. Might be too late for 13.04.

Comment: 3.8 was released yesterday (https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/2/18/476) ;), I hope that 13.04 will include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail is being developed with kernel 3.8 so it should be possible. However I have not found the information that 13.04 will offer the possibility to install to F2FS since this is not a mature FS.

Now if you want to try it with daily images of Raring there should be a way, and please share your experience)

[F2FS tools on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/f2fs-tools)

*EDIT 04/25/2013 Gparted 0.16 introduces support for F2FS so a later ubiquity version (or even backport to raring) will soon make it easy to install Ubuntu on F2FS (provided there is a warning/workaround about the Grub issue).*

Comment: As long as gparted does not have it our installer will not have it ;)

Comment: I think there is a patch in the tubes for Gparted, but for the time being people have been experimenting and Grub doesn't access F2FS partitions either.

At some point though it will be possible to duplicate a system with /boot on an ext4 partition and the rest on F2FS.

Comment: So far you can create an F2FS partition with the above-mentioned tools. On a single partition 32GB or more SSD located at /dev/sda:
`mkfs.f2fs -l f2fsonssd -o 3 /dev/sda1` (thx to Rexilion)
then you should be able to install ubuntu (with kernel 3.8 or older) in text-mode (alternate/server CD). Note that the Grub issue would still have to be addressed independently.